# Is there any way for my class to support serialisation as an XML attribute?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xml-attribute

I have a custom class that only has one property of type string.

Attempting to serialise an object of this class as an attribute using XmlSerializer results in the exception:

> XmlAttribute/XmlText cannot be used to encode complex types

Now I know I can fudge this my creating a pseudo string property in my containing type and serialising that instead, but is there any way at all to make my custom class support it intrinsically?

How do .Net classes do it (eg DateTime)?

Comment: Just checking, you have marked your class as `[Serializable]`, right?

Comment: Nope. I thought that was only required for binary serialisation?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Yes. It's the attribute that's the issue here isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to this you have to implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) and fully control how your type is serialized / deserialized. Rather overwhelming effort for such an easy task, though. People mostly get stuck with this when it comes to Nullable types.

Comment: Are you sure this will work? How does .Net know that I won't try and serialise one or more xml elements in my implementation?

Comment: You are in control of serialization so you are able to say what to write http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.writexml.aspx

Comment: I know I can say, but .Net does not know what I'm going to do, so it doesn't know whether my class can be contained in an attribute. My question is how do I tell .Net that I can be serialised to an attribute.

Comment: Could you give an example what do you want to achieve? Have you tried implementing IXmlSerializable?